# Tomcat 5.5 service not start?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat5.5

tomcat 5.5 installed properly in my laptop but their service not started.

Please give me proper solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something goes bad, I think.

Comment: Please give me proper information

Comment: Provide details atleast if you want a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **Windows** operating system you can start tomcat manually.

- Go to Task manager
- Select Services tab
- In service window select Services button
- Find Tomatcat and press start button

Answer (score 0):

Please pass some more information about your operating system, software installed, etc.

If you have **linux** (mostly **ubuntu** is used by newbies), `sudo service tomcat5 start` would be suffice and `sudo service tomcat5 status` to check its status. Dont forget to use package managers only.

I would recomend tomcat7 if resources permit you.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to port issue. Make sure the port on which Tomcat is running is free and if not try changing the port and start the service again.